# 32-bit program is unable to capture keystrokes made on a 32-bit process, but able to capture those made on a 64-bit process

Tags: c++, windows, dll, 64-bit

My environment details:

- Operating system: Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1 (64-bit Operating System)
- Compiler: Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 (Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for 80x86)
- My program main.exe and hook.dll are 32-bit
- Internet Explorer (iexplore.exe) is 64-bit
- Chrome (chrome.exe) is 32-bit

I have written a C++ program called main.exe that makes the following calls:

```
HOOKPROC callback = (HOOKPROC) GetProcAddress(dll, "keyboardHook");
HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, callback, dll, NULL);
```

The `keyboardHook` function is defined in a DLL called hook.dll. This function logs every keystroke on the console as well as a file called out.txt.

I perform the following experiment.

1. Execute main.exe on command prompt.
2. Make Internet Explorer (64-bit) as my active window and press <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> on it.
3. Make Chrome (32-bit) as my active window and press <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> on it.
4. Make command prompt my active window and kill main.exe by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

I see only the following output on the console.

```
C:\lab\keyhook>main,exe
hinstDLL: 10000000; fdwReason: 1; lpvReserved: 00000000
); scan code: 28; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 65 (A); scan code: 30; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 65 (A); scan code: 30; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 66 (B); scan code: 48; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 66 (B); scan code: 48; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 67 (C); scan code: 46; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 67 (C); scan code: 46; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 17 (◄); scan code: 29; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 67 (C); scan code: 46; transition state: 0
hinstDLL: 10000000; fdwReason: 2; lpvReserved: 00000000
hinstDLL: 10000000; fdwReason: 0; lpvReserved: 00000001
```

And I see only the following output in the file I am logging to.

```
C:\lab\keyhook>type out.txt
); scan code: 28; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 65 (A); scan code: 30; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 65 (A); scan code: 30; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 66 (B); scan code: 48; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 66 (B); scan code: 48; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 67 (C); scan code: 46; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 67 (C); scan code: 46; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 17 (◄); scan code: 29; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 67 (C); scan code: 46; transition state: 0
```

You can see that the keystrokes made on 32-bit Chrome have not been captured either in the console or in the log file.

Why is it that my 32-bit program compiled with a 32-bit C++ compiler succeeds in capturing keystrokes made on 64-bit iexplore.exe but fails to capture keystrokes made on 32-bit chrome.exe?

The [SetWindowsHookEx documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN seems to indicate that my 32-bit program should be able to capture keystrokes made on other 32-bit programs only.

> SetWindowsHookEx can be used to inject a DLL into another process. A 32-bit DLL cannot be injected into a 64-bit process, and a 64-bit DLL cannot be injected into a 32-bit process. If an application requires the use of hooks in other processes, it is required that a 32-bit application call SetWindowsHookEx to inject a 32-bit DLL into 32-bit processes, and a 64-bit application call SetWindowsHookEx to inject a 64-bit DLL into 64-bit processes. The 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs must have different names.
>
> Because hooks run in the context of an application, they must match the "bitness" of the application. If a 32-bit application installs a global hook on 64-bit Windows, the 32-bit hook is injected into each 32-bit process (the usual security boundaries apply). In a 64-bit process, the threads are still marked as "hooked." However, because a 32-bit application must run the hook code, the system executes the hook in the hooking app's context; specifically, on the thread that called SetWindowsHookEx. This means that the hooking application must continue to pump messages or it might block the normal functioning of the 64-bit processes.

Here is the complete code of my main program that invokes `SetWindowsHookEx`.

```
// Filename: main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary("hook.dll");
    if (dll == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "LoadLibrary error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HOOKPROC callback = (HOOKPROC) GetProcAddress(dll, "keyboardHook");
    if (callback == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "GetProcAddress error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, callback, dll, NULL);
    if (hook == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "SetWindowsHookEx error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    MSG messages;
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
}
```

Here is the DLL code.

```
// Filename: hook.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT keyboardHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::ofstream outputTxt("out.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    outputTxt << "nCode: " << nCode << "; wParam: " << wParam
              <<" (" << char(wParam) << "); scan code: "
              << ((lParam & 0xFF0000) >> 16)
              << "; transition state: " << ((lParam & 0x80000000) >> 31)
              << std::endl;
    outputTxt.close();

    std::cout << "nCode: " << nCode << "; wParam: " << wParam
              <<" (" << char(wParam) << "); scan code: "
              << ((lParam & 0xFF0000) >> 16)
              << "; transition state: " << ((lParam & 0x80000000) >> 31)
              << std::endl;
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    std::cout << "hinstDLL: " << hinstDLL
              << "; fdwReason: " << fdwReason
              << "; lpvReserved: " << lpvReserved << std::endl;

    return TRUE;
}
```

This is how I compile this project:

```
vcvars32.bat
cl /LD hook.cc /link user32.lib
cl main.cc /link user32.lib
```

This is what the processes look like. See that chrome.exe and main.exe are 32-bit processes whereas instances of iexplore.exe are 64-bit processes.

[image: Task Manager]

Can you explain why my observation does not match the MSDN documentation?

Comment: You cannot hook a 64-bit process with a 32-bit DLL and you cannot see std::cout output if the program you hook doesn't have a console.  You successfully hooked your own program.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes! That was the issue in my experiment. When I use `"C:\\out.txt"` as the output file path, I can see keystrokes made on 32-bit as well as 64-bit processes. I'll add an answer with the fixed code. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments by Hans Passant to this question and [this answer by manuell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20903216/1175080) helped me to understand and fix my code.

The relative path `"out.txt"` was the source of all confusion.

My 32-bit program successfully injects its 32-bit hook into 32-bit Chrome. Therefore, the hook runs in Chrome's context and the "out.txt" file is written in Chrome's working directory. Thus, the keystrokes <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> that were made on Chrome as the active window were logged at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\31.0.1650.63\out.txt".

```
C:\>type "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\31.0.1650.63\out.txt"
nCode: 0; wParam: 88 (X); scan code: 45; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 88 (X); scan code: 45; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 89 (Y); scan code: 21; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 89 (Y); scan code: 21; transition state: 1
nCode: 0; wParam: 90 (Z); scan code: 44; transition state: 0
nCode: 0; wParam: 90 (Z); scan code: 44; transition state: 1
```

This output didn't appear in the console because no console is associated with Chrome.

However, my 32-bit program cannot inject its 32-bit hook into 64-bit Internet Explorer. As a result, the hook executes in my program's context and the "out.txt" file is created in my program's working directory when it logs the keystrokes made on 64-bit Internet Explorer. This output is also logged on the console because there is a console associated with my program. This is what you saw mentioned in my question.

A simple fix to my code would be to log the keystrokes to an absolute path `"C:\\out.txt"` instead of the relative path "C:\out.txt" in hook.cc, so that I can see keystrokes made on both 32-bit programs and 64-bit programs in the same file.

Comment: +1 for taking the trouble to clearly explain what you learned